# Disable Facebook email notifications but keep them on the website

Tags: facebook, email, notifications

If I disable my notifications in the notification settings on Facebook, does that also disable the notifications on the website (little red numbers on top) or does it only disable the e-mail notifications?

I would like to receive the messages on Facebook, but not in my e-mail account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabling email notifications in Facebook only stops emails, your regular notifications within Facebook will remain. I couldn't find anything specifically saying as such in Facebook's doco, but there is a non-authoritative answer in [this comment](http://www.techf5.com/1130/stop-disable-email-notifications-from-facebook/#comments).